# Ok 2003 impala check engine light staying on..one fan replaced it was overheating because one was making a noise. Still running hot..what to do?

Tags: overheating

Fan was making  noise..replacement was put in now it is still overheating and check engine light stays on..I have added engine coolant and everything and have reset light but comes back on within a hour

Comment: What's the error code? Was coolant ever flushed and replaced? sealer use? Is the ac condenser coil, in front of the radiator, free of debris, fins not bent preventing airflow?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.